# Jquery slideToggle not working with display none css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1. The following jquery slideToggle function is not working properly.
2. The hidden content can be visible for a while but not properly visible

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mainmenu li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li>one
    <ul>
      <li class="submenu">abc</li>
      <li class="submenu">bca</li>
      <li class="submenu">cab</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>two
    <ul>
      <li class="submenu">abc</li>
      <li class="submenu">bca</li>
      <li class="submenu">cab</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: What you mean by 'properly visible'? It works fine for me...https://jsfiddle.net/tb1zb8oa/ Also, you can add .submenu class JUST to <ul> and it will work....

Answer (score 3):

instead of making `submenu` as `display: none`, try to create a wrap like `submenu-wrap` to ul and make it as `display:none`.And target this in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mainmenu li").click(function () {

            $(this).find('.submenu-wrap').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
.submenu-wrap{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
            <li>
                <ul class="submenu-wrap">
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul  class="submenu-wrap">
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add content to main-menu list, its working but due CSS positioning it's not showing properly..

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
            <li> HOME <!-- for example -->
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> ABOUT <!-- for example -->
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mainmenu li").click(function () {

            $(this).find('.submenu-wrap').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
.submenu-wrap{
  display: none;
}
 ul li {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
            <li>test-1
                <ul class="submenu-wrap">
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> test-2
                <ul  class="submenu-wrap">
                    <li class="submenu">abc</li>
                    <li class="submenu">bca</li>
                    <li class="submenu">cab</li>
                </ul>
            </li>    

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. this will also close the other submenu if you are clicking on another submenu

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mainmenu>li>span").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('.submenu').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.submenu').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

ul.mainmenu {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.mainmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

ul.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li>
    <span>One</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>bca</li>
      <li>cab</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Two</span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>bca</li>
      <li>cab</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: It works Fine but even after clicking on inner li submenu ul gets hide.
Is there any solution for this problem..??

Comment: @sagarpatil just wrap the `li` text into `span`. Check the updated answer.